# MySQL: Is it possible to display aggregate data1 and aggregate data2 within the same resulting table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have this table `mytable`:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| City   | User  | Amt |
+--------+-------+-----+
| London | John  | 100 |
| London | John  | 200 |
| London | James | 300 |
| London | James |  50 |
| Paris  | Jean  | 100 |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I want to write a query that would produce the following result:

```
+--------+-------+------------+------------+
| City   | User  | AmtPerUser | AmtPerCity |
+--------+-------+------------+------------+
| London | John  |        300 |        650 |
| London | James |        350 |        650 |
| Paris  | Jean  |        100 |        100 |
+--------+-------+------------+------------+
```

This can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.City, User, AmtPerUser, AmtPerCity
FROM
    (SELECT City, User, SUM(Amt) as AmtPerUser FROM mytable GROUP BY City, User) t1
  JOIN
     (SELECT City, SUM(Amt) as AmtPerCity FROM mytable GROUP BY City ) t2
  USING (City);
```

But this query runs too slow, because the derived tables do not have indexes.

So I wonder if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this task.

**03/25/2019 UPDATE**

Thank you for the provided solutions. I am currently still using old MySQL 5.1.
Good to know about window functions in MySQL 8.

I've tested the queries on a larger set (the data listed here, copied 3600 times to make 18K rows). This one is the best so far:

```
SELECT City, User, SUM(Amt) as AmtPerUser,
       SUM(SUM(Amt)) OVER (PARTITION BY City) as AmtPerCity
FROM mytable
GROUP BY City, User;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q5kB6ikJsc5QyPZQeYhTBw/2)**

@GordonLinoff: 43ms
My original query: 70ms
@GMB: 135ms

It also turned out that presence or absence of indexes does not contribute.

Comment: The query needs atleast index on `mytable(City, User)` that might gain extra performance

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySQL most likely won't use an index with `SUM`, because it would need to touch every record in the table.

Comment: *"most likely won't use an index with SUM, because it would need to touch every record in the table. "* i know @TimBiegeleisen it's more meant to possibly optimize the `GROUP BY` and the `JOIN` removing the need for temporary table and or filesort or a combination of both depending on MySQL version and  optimizer for his current query

Comment: So, this question is actually about how to make the query runs faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT City, User, SUM(Amt) as AmtPerUser,
       SUM(SUM(Amt)) OVER (PARTITION BY City) as AmtPerCity
FROM mytable
GROUP BY City, User;
```

Note:  This assumes MySQL 8+.

In earlier versions, your version with the `JOIN` and two `GROUP BY`s is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions along with `SELECT DISTINCT` to obtain the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    city, 
    user, 
    SUM(amt) OVER(PARTITION BY City, User) AmtPerUser,
    SUM(amt) OVER(PARTITION BY City) AmtPerCity
FROM mytable
```

Window functions usually perform better than the equivalent aggregated queries. But if you really worry about performance, then you do want to create indexes anyway (possibly a compound index on `(city, user)`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Rvmr3UEHfijtW6n2GdXnR/3)**:

```
| city   | user  | AmtPerUser | AmtPerCity |
| ------ | ----- | ---------- | ---------- |
| London | James | 350        | 650        |
| London | John  | 300        | 650        |
| Paris  | Jean  | 100        | 100        |
```

Comment: Most likely an index would not be used with `GROUP BY` and `SUM`, but I like the rest of your answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` query to get the `City` totals on another row in your output data (and a grand total row as well):

```
SELECT City, User, SUM(Amt)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY City, User WITH ROLLUP
```

Output:

```
City    User    SUM(Amt)
London  James   350
London  John    300
London  null    650
Paris   Jean    100
Paris   null    100
null    null    750
```

You can recognise the `ROLLUP` rows by the `NULL` values - the total for each city has the city name for `City` and `NULL` for `User`, while the grand total row has `NULL` for both `City` and `User`. Although this isn't exactly the format you are looking for, it will be more efficient.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLw68xBPHb7JAcBGhzBX2z/0)